# How to use $(ProjectName) an other macros in output path and other configurations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2022

I want to use the project's name in the output path property.

VisualStudio has a macro $(ProjectName).

[image]

is saved as `<OutputPath>..\bin\Debug\Plugins\%24%28ProjectName%29\</OutputPath>` in the project file.

This of course puts files into

> ..\bin\Debug\Plugins$(ProjectName)\

So how do I use the ProjectName in my output path?

I found several hints that I should replace the encoded string by

`<OutputPath>..\bin\Debug\Plugins\$(ProjectName)</OutputPath>`

But this does not have any effect. That string is neither displayed properly in Visual Studio nor does it result in the desired output path.

So what options do I have other than using build events?

`..\bin\Debug\Plugins\$(Configuration)` results in the expected output btw. so using macros is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$(MSBuildProjectName)` instead of `$(ProjectName)` solved it.